# Get week of the year after setting start day as Sunday

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, teradata

I am trying to get the week of the year after setting start of the week as Sunday.

This is required so I can mirror the Teradata logic in my python script. In Teradata the week start from Sunday. So below query returns -

```
select WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR(to_date('2019-06-01'))
21
```

But when I run that in python it returns 22

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2019, 6, 1).isocalendar()[1]
```

I tried to set the Sunday as first day of the Week, but same result

```
import calendar
import datetime
calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)
datetime.date(2019, 6, 1).isocalendar()[1]
```

Any help?

Comment: May be in python it is the 22th week, and in teradata it is the integer part of value? i am not sure, it is my hypothesis. What if try to return day of year? Is it same?

Comment: Teradata weeknumber_of_year is a little odd (to me, at least).  It's the number of weeks from the beginning of the year.  So for example, '2019-01-01' will return week number of 0, because it's 0 weeks from the beginning of the year. I think week 1 is technically the first complete week of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [`strftime("%U")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

> Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a
>   zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first
>   Sunday are considered to be in week 0.

To match Python's `isocalendar()` you can switch to ISO in Teradata, too:

```
WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR(to_date('2019-06-01'), 'ISO')
```

Btw, there's no reason to write `to_date('2019-06-01')`, simply use a date literal instead: `DATE '2019-06-01'`

Comment: My requirement was other way around... to import Teradata logic into a python script. The `strftime("%U")` did the trick.